# WPF ContextMenu slow to load

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a class library containing, among other things, a WPF ContextMenu with 10 MenuItems, of which 5 have 2 sub MenuItems. On the initial right-click, the context menu takes over 5 seconds to open (on subsequent clicks it opens almost immediately). I understand that Windows only loads objects into memory as-needed as this often happens the first time you click on a menu or control in any app. However, 5-10 seconds is way too slow. My context menu is declared & defined in the usual way, basically bare bones and with no overhead. Is there any way to pre-load it into memory or on app startup or otherwise make it open faster? Thanx.

Comment: Is any work being performed when the context menu is opened?  i.e. is anything subscribed to [ContextMenuOpening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenuopening(v=vs.110).aspx)  Or any other events?  Is the menu entirely XAML, or created in code?

Comment: Thanx for your interest. It checks to see which commands are available. I've tried it using CommandBindings and overriding OnOpened - no difference. The code is copied & pasted straight from MSDN so its boilerplate. I never add functionality until the basics work. My class library is a .dll which provides services to a client. The context menus load slightly faster when incorporated directly in the client, but this of course is not a viable solution.

Comment: If you remove the checks does the slowness go away?  Can you benchmark it with a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`? (just to try and prove that it is taking a long time)

Comment: No, there is no noticeable difference. However, it loads faster when I run the app standalone - i.e. not in Visual Studio.